# Setting X-Frame-Options in Phoenix response

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, x-frame-options

I am trying to make a [shopify](/questions/tagged/shopify) app with [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) as the backend. I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@fabian.zitter/elixir-shopify-apps-with-phoenix-part-2-7e5c1521aa36) to load my app in the shopify admin, and I need to modify `x-frame-options` header.

This is my plug:

```ex
@doc false
def init(opts \\ %{}), do: Enum.into(opts, %{})

@doc false
def call(%{params: %{"shop" => shopify_domain}} = conn, _opts) do
  IO.puts("++++++++++ Plug Call ++++++++++++++")
  IO.inspect(shopify_domain)
  # %{"shopify_domain" => shopify_domain_only} = shopify_domain
  shop = ShopifyApp.find_shop_by(shopify_domain)

  allow_shop_or_halt(conn, shop)
end

def call(conn, _opts), do: conn

defp allow_shop_or_halt(conn, nil), do: Conn.halt(conn)

defp allow_shop_or_halt(conn, shop) do
  conn
  |> Conn.put_private(:shop, shop)
  |> Conn.put_resp_header("x-frame-options", "ALLOW-FROM https://#{shop.shopify_domain}/")
end
```

But the console in the Chrome browser complains that:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading .....:
>   ALLOW-FROM https://skbeautysupply.myshopify.com/' is not a recognized
>   directive. The header will be ignored.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try downcased `allow-from`

Comment: @denis.peplin Yes I did, but didn't work. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's a documented issue. [According to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility), this does not work in Chrome or Safari. *You can do one of two things:*

---

#### 1. Don't set the `Header`

You can do this by not using `:put_secure_browser_headers` plug in the first place or deleting `x-frame-options` header (after calling it):

```ex
delete_resp_header(conn, "x-frame-options")
```

---

#### 2. Use [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)

The second option is to specify your domain in `frame-ancestors` sources in the CSP headers for full support. You may choose to use both `X-Frame-Options` *and* `Content-Security-Policy` or just CSP:

```ex
conn
|> put_resp_header("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM https://example.com")
|> put_resp_header("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors https://example.com;")
```

Answer (score -1):

I used NGINX to (un-)set these headers. I'll post the solution here because it took me a while to figure this out. Releasing a new application version was not an option.

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/application.xyz.conf*

```
    # I used this inside the location / { at the very END

    proxy_hide_header x-frame-options;
    proxy_set_header x-frame-options "ALLOW-FROM blabla";
    add_header x-frame-options "ALLOW-FROM blabla";

} # close location
```

Run `service nginx reload` to enable the change.

I know this answer has nothing to do with shopify, but it removes the header from the proxy app (phoenix).